# Calling a function when we click out side in angular popover

Tags: angularjs, css-selectors, bootstrap-popover

I am working on a UI task to display a popover when i click on a link. Once i click outside the popover, it will close. But while clicking on the link i am adding CSS styles to the link. When the popover is closed i want the applied css to be removed from the link. Any suggestions

code:

```
<div class="popover-border" uib-popover-template="'template.html'" popover- 
placement="bottom" popover-trigger="'outsideClick'" popover-class="test- 
popover">
```

Template for the popover content

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template.html">
<h1> Hello</h1>
</script>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow!
Please add the code that you implemented.

I'll try to help you without reading your code:
When clicking on the link, add a class that has the styles.
When closing the popover, remove this class.

Comment: Thanks @AlonShmiel for a quick reply. Updated my post with code. Here i'm using bootstrap popover component. while opening i am adding the css classes using javascript. But when i click outside the popover will close but the style remains the same

Comment: Do you have onClose function for popover?
You pasted code but I don't see somthing like this.
If you create jsfiddle/codepen/etc, I will help you :)

Comment: popover doesn't have any onClose function. Thanks for creating the fiddle, there is a directive called popover-is-open. But i am not sure if it can solve my issue

Comment: Did you see my answer? If it helps, please mark my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

`popover-trigger="'outsideClick'"`

to:

`popover-trigger="outsideClick"`

Working example is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WvM66FiRnw2LozgwPj8m?p=preview)

Comment: The example you have provided will help me in removing the popover but my concern is i added some css styles while clicking on the button. please check this  [Link](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/Ok1pyTD1wTAC8bOK?preview)

Comment: issue is resolved i created a variable and assigned it to popover-is-open and using it to change the css styles